# NoSuchRecordException when saving Entity on Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am able to save an entity on my local PC using Neo4j Desktop version "5.3.0" but when I have the same exact same code and try saving the entity on the remote server with older version of "4.2.5, I am getting the below error;

```
2023-05-11 09:48:13.525  WARN 90586 --- [  poolThread-96] .n.c.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator : Don't know how to translate exception of type class org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.NoSuchRecordException
Exception in thread "poolThread-96" org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.NoSuchRecordException: Expected a result with a single record, but this result contains at least one more. Ensure your query returns only one record.
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository

public interface OntologyRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Ontology, String> {
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class OntologyService {
      @Autowired
      private OntologyRepository ontologyRepository;

      public void saveProfile(Ontology ontology) {
        ontologyRepository.save(ontology);
      }
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Node("Profile")
@Component
public class Ontology extends Profile implements Cloneable {

    @Id
    private String hash;

    @Transient
    private long id;

    //etc.
}
```

In the Service class, If the return type was also the object that I am trying to save, I would understand the error but that is not the case. I am just trying to save without querying any data. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error message `Expected a result with a single record, but this result contains at least one more. Ensure your query returns only one record.`, states that there is more than one record, with the same primary key. I believe this is due to your `hash` key not being unique across nodes, as it is marked with `@Id`. If you are not assigning `hash` manually, then you should auto-generate it like this:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Node("Profile")
@Component
public class Ontology extends Profile implements Cloneable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generatorClass = UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    private String hash;

    @Transient
    private long id;

    //etc.
}
```

This should resolve the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had the code to define a unique ID for the hash but tried your suggestion as well. I created a new Neo4j container and a DB from scratch and ran the process there once again. However, I could only save 120 Profiles. After that, I started to get the same error. I am thinking it could be the Neo4j container (v4.2.5.) and the version since I am able to save as much data using Neo4j Desktop v5.3.0.

Comment: Might be the case, yeah.